# How to change a variable in one class through another's function?

Tags: c++

I have two classes listed within a main one, one needs to take a variable from another and do arithmetics with it, i.e. genuinely change it.

```
class CHARACTERS
{
public:
    CHARACTERS();
    //...other functions yada-yada...//

    class MAGE
    {
    public:
        MAGE();
        int hpm; // That's the variable I'm talking about
                //...yada-yada...//
        friend class KNIGHT;
    };

    class KNIGHT
    {
    public:
        KNIGHT();
        //...yada-yada...//
        void slash(); // Reduces the hpm variable
        friend class MAGE;
    };
};
```

Any attempts to successfully get the `slash()` function working ultimately ended in failure, closest I've gotten is:

```
void CHARACTERS::KNIGHT::slash()
{
    MAGE hp; // Creating an object
    std::cout << "Before:" << hp.hpm;
    hp.hpm -= 35;
    std::cout << "After:" hp.hpm;
}
```

"Before" shows 200 (as intended, hpm was set to it initially), "after" 165 (as intended too), but in `main()` the actual hpm variable is still 200! I guess it merely changed the `hp` and not the actual `hpm` variable. Overall, I think I'm in the right direction with the code but missing something crucial, any help?

Comment: `MAGE hp;` creates a temporary object that only exist inside that function. Please add a [mre] so we can see how you are trying to use this function.

Comment: *"but in `main()` the actual hpm variable is still 200!"* -- I don't see a `main` function in your [mre], so your question is incomplete. (It shouldn't be hard to add this function -- keep in mind that you are demonstrating your issue, not your game. So the function should not need much more than defining "the actual hpm variable" and calling `slash()`.)

Comment: *"one needs to take a variable from another and do arithmetics with it"* -- where in your code do you demonstrate the taking? I see the code for the modification (subtracting 35), but not the taking.

Answer (score 1):

```
    MAGE hp; // Creating an object
```

`slash()` creates this brand new object called, `hp`, fresh from the factory, with the original manufacturer's warranty. This is what the above statement means in C++: it's an object definition. It creates a new object. After a magical incantation, if you will, a new object materializes into existence, right here. It's name is `hp`. That's what this means.

```
    std::cout << "Before:" << hp.hpm;
    hp.hpm -= 35;
    std::cout << "After:" hp.hpm;
```

This does a few things to this object, then this function returns, and the `hp` object gets destroyed. It becomes no more. It starts pining for the fjords. It ceases to exist. It becomes an ex-object. When you declare an object, in this manner, in a function or an inner scope, that object gets automatically destroyed when execution leaves this scope, for any reason, that's how automatically-scoped objects in C++ work.

> but in main() the actual hpm variable is still 200

Whatever that mysterious object in `main()` is, it must be some other unrelated `MAGE` object that has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with this `hp` object that was created and destroyed in `slash()`.

Perhaps you have another object declared in `main()` that's also named "hp". That's fine, but C++ does not work this way. Just because two variables get defined in different parts of your program with the same name it doesn't mean that both of them are the same object. They're not. Your `hp` object in `slash()` is a `MAGE`. Another function somewhere, in some other part of your program, can declare an `int` with the same name. Each object in a C++ program is a unique, distinct entity, that gets created and destroyed whenever, well, it gets created and destroyed.

A good C++ textbook explains how objects work in C++, what their scope of existance is, the different kinds of object scope in C++: automatic, and dynamic, and how they work, and how to use them properly. If you have any ***specific*** questions about object lifetime scope in C++ you can ask a ***specific*** follow-up question about it.

Comment: "Whatever that mysterious object in main() is, it must be some other unrelated MAGE object that has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with this hp object that was created and destroyed in slash()."

I do actually have a different MAGE object in main() -- how do I make it so the slash() function actually affects the hpm variable in that MAGE object?

Comment: Passing it by reference, into `slash()` would be one of many ways of doing. But not the only way. What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from, or the topic of your C++ class where this was given to you, by your C++ instructor, as a practice problem? Knowing that will help me point you in the right direction. Perhaps your practice program is expected to use a different approach, and doing something else will keep you from getting full credit.

Comment: We are learning about classes and objects right now, we are basically starting to actually deal with C++ after getting enough good understanding of C#. The code is partly me practicing and partly my idea I want to realize into something cool.

Comment: In this regard, C++ and C# work the same way. This wouldn't work like that in C#, either. However, you will do yourself a huge, huge favor if you completely forget everything that you know about C# while learning C++. C++ is not C#, and in C++ objects work in many fundamentally different ways than they do in C#. Given very similar syntax it's easy to assume something about C++ objects because that's what happens in C#. Nearly all the time the assumption turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

With your current design, you need to tell `KNIGHT` which `MAGE` is being attacked. You do this by passing a reference to the `MAGE`-to-be-slashed.

```
class KNIGHT {
   ...
   void slash(MAGE& mage) const {
      mage.hpm -= 35;
   }
};

// in main
int main() {
    KNIGHT knight;
    MAGE mage;
    knight.slash(mage);
}
```

That will get it working for *this specific* combination of `CHARACTER`s.

Think about how this will scale when you want the `MAGE` to `slash` the `KNIGHT`. Or if you want the `KNIGHT` to `slash` a `BARBARIAN`. A more scalable approach might be to have a damage class that describes the damage type (slashing, piercing, fire, etc.) and number.

If `CLASS A` attacks `CLASS B`, the responsibility would now be:

1. `CLASS A` generates a `Damage` object.
2. `CLASS B` receives and processes a `Damage` object.

`KNIGHT`s no longer need to know about every single other `CHARACTER` type in the game. They can now focus on just the type of damage they create.

```
struct Damage {
    enum class Type {
        slash,
        pierce,
        blunt,
        fire,
        ...etc...
    }

    Type type{Type::slash};
    int value{0};
};

class KNIGHT {
public:
    Damage do_slash() const {
        return Damage{Damage::Type::slash, 35};
    }

    Damage do_punch() const {
        return Damage{Damage::Type::blunt, 10};
    }
};

class MAGE {
public:
    void receive_damage(const Damage& damage) {
        switch(damage.type) {
        case Damage::Type::slash:
            // resistant to slashing for some reason
            hp -= (damage.value / 2);
            break;
        default:
            // all other damage is 1:1
            hp -= damage.value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you've learned polymorphism, I recommend using THAT. But based on your question it looks like you haven't gotten to that yet.